# How to use pd.json_normalize to retrieve the data I need

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have this JSON list in Python:

```json
[{'id': 'TC2-FFA',
  'shortCode': 'TC2-FFA',
  'dataSet': {'datumPrecision': 2,
   'id': 'TC2_37',
   'shortCode': 'TC2_37',
   'shortDescription': 'Clean Continent to US Atlantic coast',
   'displayGroup': 'BCTI',
   'datumUnit': 'Worldscale',
   'data': [{'value': 156.11, 'date': '2023-03-06'}],
   'apiIdentifier': 'RDSX9KRCHQI9TVGID5O7XQGBP1KKBZ0F'},
  'datumUnit': 'WS',
  'datumPrecision': 3,
  'projectionStartOn': '2005-01-04T00:00:00',
  'projectionEndOn': '2023-03-06T00:00:00',
  'apiIdentifier': 'RPSBTGHKN64SV91SV9R3492RCH33D2OH'},
 {'id': 'TC2$-FFA',
  'shortCode': 'TC2$-FFA',
  'dataSet': {'datumPrecision': 2,
   'id': 'TC2_37',
   'shortCode': 'TC2_37',
   'shortDescription': 'Clean Continent to US Atlantic coast',
   'displayGroup': 'BCTI',
   'datumUnit': 'Worldscale',
   'data': [{'value': 156.11, 'date': '2023-03-06'}],
   'apiIdentifier': 'RDSX9KRCHQI9TVGID5O7XQGBP1KKBZ0F'},
  'datumUnit': '$/mt',
  'datumPrecision': 3,
  'projectionStartOn': '2010-05-10T00:00:00',
  'projectionEndOn': '2023-03-06T00:00:00',
  'apiIdentifier': 'RPSH1H9454DYUE7G8CLHVLFPJZ3BVM77'}]
```

How could I use `pandas.json_normalize` to only retrieve the data `shortCode` (or `id`) and `data` under `dataSet` (`dataSet`--`data`--`value` and `date`)?

This is the desired dataframe:

```
  shortCode  data.value   data.date
0   TC2-FFA      156.11  2023-03-06
1   TC2$-FFA      156.11  2023-03-06
```

I tried

```
pd.json_normalize(lst_object, record_path=['dataSet', ['shortCode', ['data', 'value'], ['data', 'date']])
```

but it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be confusing.

You want all values from `dataSet.data` so they are your records.

You can then use meta to bring in `shortCode`

```
pd.json_normalize(
   data, 
   record_path=['dataSet', 'data'], 
   meta=['shortCode']
)
```

```
    value        date shortCode
0  156.11  2023-03-06   TC2-FFA
1  156.11  2023-03-06  TC2$-FFA
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `record_path` and pass parameter values for `meta_path` and `record_prefix`

```
pd.json_normalize(lst_object, 
                  meta=['shortCode'], 
                  record_path=['dataSet', 'data'], 
                  record_prefix='data.')
```

Result

```
   data.value   data.date shortCode
0      156.11  2023-03-06   TC2-FFA
1      156.11  2023-03-06  TC2$-FFA
```